# A random number (4) just appears in my php project

Tags: php, html, css

Im building a php project.

This is the structure

[image]

This is my init.php

```
<?php

use App\Core\Container;

require_once __DIR__."/../autoloader.php";

require_once __DIR__."/Core/Container.php"; 

$container = new Container();
```

which gets used within the index.php

```
<?php

require "./src/init.php";

$pathinfo = $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"];

$routes= [
    "/team" => ['TeamController',
    'showTeampage'],
    ];


if(isset($routes[$pathinfo])){

   
    $controllername = $routes[$pathinfo][0];
    $method = $routes[$pathinfo][1];

    
    $controller = $container->make($controllername);
  
}
```

This is the container php where the problem occurs:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Core;

use PDO;
use App\Team\TeamController;
use App\Team\TeamRepository;


class Container   {

    public $storage = [];
    public $buildManuals = [];

    public function __construct() {
    
        $this->buildManuals = [
            'pdo'=> function () {
                $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=vanillaPHP;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
                $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);
                return $pdo;
            },
            'TeamController'=> function() {
                $controller =  new TeamController();          
            },
            'TeamRepository'=>function() {
                 return new TeamRepository($this->make("pdo"));
            },
           
        ];
    }


    public function make(String $string) {
            if(empty($this->storage[$string]) ) {
                $this->storage[$string] = $this->buildManuals[$string]();
            }
            return $this->storage[$string];
    }
```

When Im entering the following URI he makes a TeamController onject I have tested it.
But he prints out the number 4 in UI for what ever reason. Why is this happening?

[image]

This is my TeamController class btw

```
namespace App\Team;

use App\Core\AbstractController;
use App\Team\TeamRepository;

class TeamController {
    public $name ="test";

    // public function __construct(Teamrepository $teamRepo)
    // {
    //     $this->teamRepo = $teamRepo; 
    // }

    public function hi() {
        echo "hi";
    }
    
    // public function showTeampage() {    
    //    $teammembers = $this->teamRepo->fetchAll();
    //    $this->render($this->teamRepo->getTableName(),
    //    [
    //        'params'=>$teammembers
    //     ]);
    // }
}
```

This is the viewfield for the team:

```
<?php require __DIR__."../../../Components/Head.php"; ?>

<p>Hi im the team view</p>

<!-- TODO: display the team data in a beautiful way -->

<?php foreach($params as $teammember): ?>
  <p> 
      <!-- <?php echo $teammember->firstname ?> -->
  </p>

<?php
endforeach;
?>

<?php require __DIR__."../../../Components/Footer.php"; ?>
```

And this is the Components/Head.php:

```
<?php

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>The company</title>
  </head>
<body>
```

Comment: What's in the View-file that rendered?

Comment: I have added it now.